# Second Level Property Binding exception on Win XP(x86) OS but not Win 7(x64)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I am stumped.   I have the following line on my c# AddressForm

`lkuCounty.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", Address, "County.CountyID", true);`

This works great on 64bit Win7 boxes but on Win XP 32bit machines I get the following Exception:

```
Type:        System.ArgumentException    
Message:     Cannot bind to the property or column CountyID on the DataSource.    
Parameter name: dataMember
```

I am guessing I am missing some nuance and would really appreciate some help.

Here are my classes(no constructors) which are in a seperate project (*myproject.Common*)

```
public class County 
{ 
    public short? CountyID { get; set; } 

    public string CountyName { get; set; } 
}
public class Address 
{ 
    public int AddressID { get; set; } 

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; } 

    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; } 

    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; } 

    public string City { get; set; } 

    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public County County { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: have  you tried a clean build?

Comment: Yup, still doesn't work.  I am pretty stumped.  At this point I think I will just have to replace it with a CountyID property and dump the County Class.  It just bothers' me that I don't know why this dosen't work.

Comment: what control are you binding to?

Comment: standard textbox or DevExpress textboxedit.  Tried both.

Comment: Here, with the same problem, did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

check spell e.g. upper/lower case

Comment: Thanks I will but could that really be the issue when it works on 64bit Win7 but doesn't on 32bit WinXP?

Comment: I do not know exactly, just say a guess

Comment: No problem, I appreciate it and I will still double check.  Thanks