# DataBinding : Second level property exception on x86 OS

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, x86

I'm having an exception when trying to bind a `textbox` control to a second level property, this exception occurs only on a `x86 OS`.

**Code :**

```
txCode.DataBinding.Add("Text", CurrentObject, "CustomerInfo.Code");
```

**Error message** :

> Could not bind to property or column Code on the DataSource. Parameter
>
> name : dataMember

**Related posts :**

- [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300414/second-level-property-binding-exception-on-win-xpx86-os-but-not-win-7x64)
- [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575698/winforms-binding-source-with-datamember-down-multiple-levels)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: winforms doesn't support deep property binding. Use WPF instead.

Comment: Under x64 os it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more like workaround than a solution :

I've change this code :

```
txCode.DataBinding.Add("Text", CurrentObject, "CustomerInfo.Code");
```

To this code

```
txCode.DataBinding.Add("Text", CurrentObject.CustomerInfo, "Code");
```

And it works fine. I'll be gratefull if someone explains this behaviour.